# Equivalence of ordered field and an order relation

Tags: real-analysis, abstract-algebra

I found this theorem in 'Set Theory and Structure of Arithmetic by Hamilton and Landin'
A field K is an ordered field with respect to a subset P if
and only if there is a binary relation < on K such that
(a) for all x, y belong to K one and only one of
x < y, x = y, y < x,
holds;
(b) for all x, y, z belonging to K, if x < y and y < z, then x < z;
(c) for all x, y, z belonging to K, if x < y, then x + z < y + z;
(d) for all x, y, z belonging to K, if x < y and < z, then xz < yz.
**Moreover, the set P with respect to which K is ordered is the set
P = {x \x is in K and O < x}**.

I got the proof of rest of theorem. But not the part that: fir such order relation, only P will be as given. And I have a question for given P, can I define 2 order relation on set.
This I know for a given orederd field I can find 2 P. But my question is taking only one P

Comment: A better statement would be: ${<}\mapsto \{\,x\in K\mid 0<x\,\}$ is a natural bijection between order relations with (a),(b),(c),(d) on $K$  and subsets $P$ of $K$ with $P+P\subseteq P$, $P\cdot P\subseteq K$, $K=P\cup\{0\}\cup {-P}$. So yes, if there are several $P$ possible, then there are also several $<$ possible and vice versa

Comment: Yes thats okey. But you said for given P or <, <↦{x∈K∣0<x} is a natural bijection between order relations with (a),(b),(c),(d) on K and subsets P of K with P+P⊆P, P⋅P⊆K, K=P∪{0}∪−P. Does this bijection unique? and does for given <, P is unique

Comment: @hagen von Eitzen how can we prove theorem you mentioned

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $K$ be a field.
Let $$\mathscr O=\{\,{<}\subseteq K^2\mid \text{conditions (a), (b), (c), (d) hold for $<$}\,\}$$
be the set of order realations on $K$ (that are compatible with the field operations).
Let 
$$ \mathscr P=\{\,P\subseteq K\mid P+P\subseteq P, P\cdot P\subseteq P, K=P\sqcup\{0\}\sqcup(-P)\,\}$$
be the set of possible positive sets of $K$.

**Claim:** Then we can define two maps
$$ \begin{align}f\colon \mathscr O&\to \mathscr P\\{<}&\mapsto \{\,x\in K\mid 0<x\,\}\end{align}$$
and
$$ \begin{align}g\colon \mathscr P&\to \mathscr O\\P&\mapsto \{\,(x,y)\in K\mid y-x\in P\,\}\end{align}$$

First one needs to show that the maps map to the right set as claimed. To show that $f({<})=\{\,x\in K\mid 0<x\,\}\in\mathscr P$, note that $0<x$ and $0<y$ imply $x<x+y$ by (c) and then $0<x+y$ by (b); hence $f({<})+f({<})\subseteq f({<})$. Similarly, (d) gives us $f({<})\cdot f({<})\subseteq f({<})$. By (a), for each $x\in K$ exactly one of $0<x$, $0=x$, $x<0$ hold; by (c), $x<0$ is equivalent to $0<-x$; hence $K=P\sqcup\{0\}\sqcup(-P)$. In summary, $f({<})\in \mathscr P$ for all ${<}\in\mathscr O$.

Next consider $g(P)$ for some $P\in\mathscr P$. Assume $(x,y)\in g(P)$ and $(y,z)\in g(P)$. Then $y-x\in P$ and $z-y\in P$, hence from $P+P\subseteq P$, we get $z-x=(z-y)+(y-x)\in P$, i.e. $(x,z)\in g(P)$, that is condition (b).
For $ (x,y)\in g(P)$ and $z\in K$  $(y+z)-(x+z)=y-x\in P$, hence condition (c) holds.
Assume $(x,y)\in g(P)$ and $(0,z)\in g(P)$. Then to show that $(xz,yz)\in g(P)$ note that
$yz-xz = (y-x)(z-0) \in P$ as product of numbers in $P$; hence condition (d).
Finaolly, if $x,y\in K$, then $x-y$ is either in $P$ or equals $0$ or is in $-P$. In the first case $(x,y)\in g(P)$, in the second $x=y$, in the third $(y,x)\in g(P)$, and these are mutually exclusive; hence condition (a). We conclude that $g(P)\in\mathscr O$ for all $P\in\mathscr P$.

To see that $f,g$ are not just some maps, but are in fact bijections, note that $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are the identity maps:
$(x,y)\in g(f({<}))$ is equivalent to  $y-x\in f({<})$, is equivalent to $0<y-x$ and by condition (c) to $x<y$.
And $x\in f(g(P))$ is equivalent to $(0,x)\in g(P)$, is equivalent to $x=x-0\in P$.